# IP camera - nexus 235fw. How to reset ip address

Tags: camera, ip-camera

I have this IP camera, Nexus CCTV 235FW. I can't connect to it anymore. Is there anyway I can reset it?
I think it happens after I changed the admin password. It is connected thought WiFi, but I have also tried with cable, without any luck.

I have also tried to search after the camera with the Search Tools, but still no luck.

Another thing, I can't even see the camera in the router's list over connected units.

Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was a router I had between my main router and the camera. Because after I got the router reset, I got that connection again. Just strange, because I just moved the router from one place to another without changing the setup. But now everything works again.